# SQL Server: Select from @variable_table_name (problem with nested variables)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select form a variable table name, which seems to not work in SQL Server (see example nr 2).

I tried making an intermediate step that creates a string with my variable table name as static text (see example nr3), but that failed too, probably because I have nested variables.

Can anyone help me fix it?

```
------------Example Nr 1--------------
-- Working query without variable Table

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @Sql = 'SELECT ';
SELECT @Sql = @Sql +'['+[Modell Pset (S1 Slab)]+']'+ ' AS ''' +''+[C3D Pset (S1 Slab)]+''', ' FROM [MTO_Psets_S1_Slab]
PRINT @sql

--Result of "print @sql": SELECT [c3d:abschnitt] AS 'Abschnitt', [ALL] AS 'Eigenschaft_1', [ALL] AS 'Eigenschaft_2', [Geschoss] AS 'Geschoss', [ALL] AS 'Ist_Aussen', [ALL] AS 'Material_1', [ALL] AS 'Material_2', [ALL] AS 'Objekt', [c3d:teilprojekt] AS 'Teilprojekt', 

SET @Sql = (SELECT LEFT(@Sql, LEN(@Sql)-1));
SET @Sql = @Sql + ' FROM [modell_properties_slab]';
EXEC sp_executesql @Sql;

------------Example Nr 2--------------
-- When I replace table with a variable, the query doesn't work anymore

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @table = '[MTO_Psets_S1_Slab]'
SET @Sql = 'SELECT ';
SELECT @Sql = @Sql +'['+[Modell Pset (S1 Slab)]+']'+ ' AS ''' +''+[C3D Pset (S1 Slab)]+''', ' FROM @table
SET @Sql = (SELECT LEFT(@Sql, LEN(@Sql)-1));
SET @Sql = @Sql + ' FROM [modell_properties_slab]';
EXEC sp_executesql @Sql

-- Error message:    
-- Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Line 24     
-- Must declare the table variable "@Table".

------------Example Nr 3--------------
-- When I rewrite the query to have the table inside the apostrophes,   
-- it doesn't work (compare the result of "print @sql" with the example nr1)

declare @slab nvarchar(MAX) ='slab'
DECLARE @intermediate_step nvarchar(MAX);
set  @intermediate_step = '''[''[Modell Pset (S1 Slab)]+'']''+ '' AS '''''' +''''+[C3D Pset (S1 Slab)]+'''''', '' FROM [MTO_Psets_S1_'+@Slab+']'
print @intermediate_step

--Result of "print @intermediate_step": '['[Modell Pset (S1 Slab)]+']'+ ' AS ''' +''+[C3D Pset (S1 Slab)]+''', ' FROM [MTO_Psets_S1_slab]

DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(MAX);
SET @Sql = 'SELECT ';
SELECT @Sql = @Sql + @intermediate_step
print @sql
--Result of "print @sql": SELECT '['[Modell Pset (S1 Slab)]+']'+ ' AS ''' +''+[C3D Pset (S1 Slab)]+''', ' FROM [MTO_Psets_S1_slab]

SET @Sql = (SELECT LEFT(@Sql, LEN(@Sql)-1));
SET @Sql = @Sql + ' FROM [modell_properties_slab]';
EXEC sp_executesql @Sql;
```

I'll attach the tables i used in the query and the result table from the working query "example nr 1" as JPG: MTO_Psets_S1_Slab, modell_properties_slab, Result query

[image: MTO_Psets_S1_Slab]
[image: modell_properties_slab]
[image: Result table]

MTO_Psets_S1_Slab
modell_properties_slab
Result query

Comment: `'[' + @variable +']'` isn't injection safe; use `QUOTENAME`. Also never declare a (dynamic) object name an `MAX` length, use `sysname`.

Comment: _seems to not work in SQL server_. what error you got.? I think, you didn't concat the table to `@sql`

Comment: To Pugal: Error message: Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Line 24 Must declare the table variable "@Table". (see example nr 2)

Comment: @Daiva, you can use like `SELECT @Sql = @Sql +'[[Modell Pset (S1 Slab)]]  AS  [C3D Pset (S1 Slab)]  FROM ' + @table `. But I am not sure that why you use, `SET @Sql = @Sql + ' FROM [modell_properties_slab]';`.

Comment: @Pugal: The part `SELECT @Sql = @Sql +'['+[Modell Pset (S1 Slab)]+']'+ ' AS ''' +''+[C3D Pset (S1 Slab)]+''', ' FROM [MTO_Psets_S1_Slab]` generates the following string: `SELECT [c3d:abschnitt] AS 'Abschnitt', [ALL] AS 'Eigenschaft_1', [ALL] AS 'Eigenschaft_2', [Geschoss] AS 'Geschoss', [ALL] AS 'Ist_Aussen', [ALL] AS 'Material_1', [ALL] AS 'Material_2', [ALL] AS 'Objekt', [c3d:teilprojekt] AS 'Teilprojekt' ` using the values from the table [MTO_Psets_S1_Slab]. I than use the generated string to query another table [modell_properties_slab].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the query like this and it works:

```
exec('

declare @t as table ([C3D Pset (S1 '+@slab+')] nvarchar (100), [Modell Pset (S1 '+@slab+')] nvarchar (100));
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(MAX);

insert @t ([C3D Pset (S1 '+@slab+')] , [Modell Pset (S1 '+@slab+')] )
select * from [MTO_Psets_S1_'+@slab+']

SET @Sql = ''SELECT '';
SELECT @Sql = @Sql +''[''+[Modell Pset (S1 Slab)]+'']''+ '' AS '''''' +''''+[C3D Pset (S1 Slab)]+'''''', '' FROM @t

SET @Sql = (SELECT LEFT(@Sql, LEN(@Sql)-1));
SET @Sql = @Sql + '' FROM [modell_properties_'+@slab+']'';
EXEC sp_executesql @Sql
')
```